# Challenge in Implementing Service Account Key Rotation

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Anyone has suggestions on how to implement automated key rotation for service account credentials used in the cloud function, AppEngine, GKE.
GCP has added this as one of the recommended security policies for cloud-native services. We can find APIs/client libraries to generate a new private key for the existing service account. But we don't really get how to update the newly generated key on the application deployed in AppEngine, cloud function during runtime.

Comment: If you are using the Google managed service accounts (the default ones created by Google for those services), then the key rotation is managed for you. If you are creating service accounts and then assigning them to services, you manage rotation.

Comment: Just to be sure to understand. You have deployed Cloud Function App Engine and GKE workloads with service account key files?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere - yes I have deployed my CF, App Engine, GKE workloads with service account key files. My app is built using nodejs. Nodejs google cloud client libraries like for cloud storage, firebase, it all accepts service account key file name path as a parameter to get initialized. I dont find a right way to update the service account file which is already in use by app hosted on the cloud

Comment: I do not recommend using service account JSON key files for credentials. Use the default service account assigned to each service. Secure and key rotation is handled for you.

Answer (score 4):

When you are on Google Cloud components, you don't have to use service account key files. It's a bad practice (even if presented as "standard" in too many tutorials, even Google Cloud tutorials!).

A service account key file is a nightmare to manage. It's a file. You can copy it, you can send it by email, you can even commit it in source repository (maybe public repo!!). In addition, you need to keep it secure and to rotate it regularly...

The best way to simplify this, is to not use them and to rely on Google Cloud component identity. *Of course, for all external component, like a CI/CD, an on prem app (or on other cloud provider), the service account key file is the best way to be authenticated on Google Cloud*

- For Cloud Functions, you can use [Cloud Functions Identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity)
- For GKE, you can use [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)
- For App Engine, you can rely on the [App Engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/service-account)
- For you local development, perform a `gcloud auth application-default login` to create a default credential with your own user account

In each case, you can recover the [default credential](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs) in your code. ([here an example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs) of a simple credential, without client library, only Google OAuth2 lib)

*Note: For some operation, App Engine default service account isn't usable (generate an identity token based on metadata servers or changing the scope of the access_token). For this, I recommend you to [impersonate service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#permissions_for_service_accounts) instead of using service account key file*